# How to skip pre_auth_filter

Tags: spring, rest, grails, filter, pre-authentication

I have a Grails 3 application using spring security. I am using pre_auth_filter for preauthentication purpose. For some urls I want to bypass pre_auth filter alone. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The way you skip a filter is defined on `application.groovy`:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    [pattern: '/public/**', filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/exclude/**', filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-excludedFilter']
]
```